# How do I delete a Kubernetes Namespace with a Cronjob?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, docker-desktop

I have a cron that's I'm testing for another project that is supposed to delete a namespace called "test" every minute.

I have set up a ServiceAccount, ClusterRole, and RoleBinding as shown below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: test
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: test
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["namespaces"]
  verbs: ["delete", "get", "list"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test # This will bind the role and service account
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: test
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

My Cronjob is as follows:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: kill-ns
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: test
          containers:
          - name: kill-ns
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command:
            - kubectl
            args:
            - delete
            - namespace
            - test
          restartPolicy: Never
```

I get the following error on from the job.

> Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces "test" is forbidden: User
> "system:serviceaccount:default:test" cannot delete resource
> "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "test"

I thought my apiGroups was the issue it was not. apiGroups is [""] for namespaces.

I'm currently using docker desktop locally.

Edit: I am deploying the job in the default namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use ClusterRoleBinding instead of RoleBinding. RoleBinding only allows access to resources in the namespace of the service account while ClusterRoleBinding allows cluster-wide access.

Comment: It would also helpful to add that it's possible to restrict permission to particular namespaces `resourceNames` (otherwise that permission looks too dangerous).

Comment: That makes sense but why does something like this work to delete a deployment?
`---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test # This will bind the role and service account
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole 
  name: test 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
`

Comment: @zerkms Can I use resourceNames to exclude namespaces or is it only inclusive?

Comment: It's only inclusive. So if you don't have a pre-defined list of names that can be deleted it won't help.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I had to had to add the `namespace: default` to the service account list item in addition to changing the RoleBinding to a ClusterRoleBinding. The test namespace is deleted.